# Codeigniter: php not working in the view!

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have just moved my working codeigniter site to a new xampp installation on new computer and now when the view loads the php inside the view doesn’t work!! e.g. the addresses in my links have the code  in them instead of the base address of the site!!!

Can anyone explain this strange behavior???

(using windows 7)

Thanks!

jk

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code and the output from the code.

Comment: What was the platform of the old installation?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is likely that your PHP configuration on your XAMPP install isn't configured to allow PHP short tags, eg: `<?=$foo;?>` such that only `<?php echo $foo; ?>` will work. You can manually change all of these instances or you can edit a value in application/config/config.php to have CodeIgniter rewrite short codes in your views. I think it is: `rewrite_short_tags`

Alternatively you can change the setting in your php.ini configuration file which I believe is accessible by right clicking on the XAMPP icon in your taskbar's notification area. See: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 1):

Turns out short codes were set to off in the php.ini !!